# How can I clone a plugin repository and use the modified repository in my code

Tags: flutter, dart, github, flutter-plugin

I want to clone a repository to my github account [Repository link](https://github.com/tulip/osm_flutter), then I want to make changes to the code and use the updated project in my vs code project.
For now i have only forked the repository and using it like this

```
dependencies:
  hive: ^2.2.3
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_osm_plugin:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/tulip/osm_flutter
  #flutter_osm_plugin: ^0.42.0
```

I get the following errors

```
[rider] flutter pub get
Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock...
Running "flutter pub get" in rider...
Resolving dependencies...
Error on line 20, column 11: Invalid description in the "flutter_osm_plugin" pubspec on the "flutter_osm_interface" dependency: "./flutter_osm_interface" is a relative path, but this isn't a local pubspec.
   ╷
20 │     path: ./flutter_osm_interface
   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
pub get failed
command: "/Users/pannam/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart __deprecated_pub --directory . get --example"
pub env: {
  "FLUTTER_ROOT": "/Users/tulip/development/flutter",
  "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "vscode.dart-code:flutter_cli:get",
  "PUB_CACHE": "/Users/tulip/.pub-cache",
}
exit code: 65

exit code 65
```

Do i need to create a local repo in my device, using Mac, if so can you please let me know where i am going wrong? I tried searching in the internet and followed the steps but to no vail.

Comment: Having forked the repo, then clone a local copy - into a sibling folder of your main project. Finally, change your dependency to: `    path: ../osm_flutter` (or whatever you called the cloned local folder). Now, when you edit your local copy of osm_flutter, those changes will be visible in your main project (as it depends on that local copy). When you are happy with the changes, you can push them back to your fork.

Comment: Well! The only solution that worked, smart and simple. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I review your issue. Try the below thing inside your plugin's pubspec.yaml.

```
dependencies:
  flutter_osm_interface:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/jesussmile/osm_flutter/tree/master/flutter_osm_interface
```

Comment: `fatal: repository 'https://github.com/jesussmile/osm_flutter/tree/master/flutter_osm_interface/' not found` I need to clone the osm_flutter repo itself, the folders, flutter_osm_interface and example is causing a problem

Comment: Could you please try it and create a `OSMFlutter` widget ?

Comment: add repository parameter below the homepage in `flutter_osm_interface's` pubspec.yaml like this.

repository: `https://github.com/jesussmile/osm_flutter/tree/master/flutter_osm_interface `**and** modify homepage by this `https://github.com/jesussmile/osm_flutter/tree/master/flutter_osm_interface`

Comment: cool! thanx finally getting somewhere, what do you mean by `**and** modify homepage by this https://github.com/jesussmile/osm_flutter/tree/master/flutter_osm_interface ` , which homepage are you talking about ? I already edited flutter_osm_interface homepage as you said

Comment: Glad  it helps you. Well in `pubspec.yaml` `homepage` is an optional parameter and basically `homepage` URL pointing to the package's source code repository. In your case it points to your plugin's homepage, not your interface's homepage, that's why I said to update it.
``
Please refer [to this link](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#homepage) for a better understanding. **and** also refer [firebase_core](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core), how they are doing with interface.